# How to display one form details at a time on click of edit/view in formarray using angular8

Tags: angular, forms, formarray

i have list of data which i am displaying in a table, on click of edit, one below the other entries are coming, but i want one edit fields to be filled at a time, rather than opening all sections based on edit or view button, latest edit/view clicked row must display the section, and based on click of save, i need to send all the rows for the final save.

TS:

```
 editw9(w9,mode) {
   console.log(w9);
   console.log(mode);
   if("viewMode" || "editMode" ) {
     this.hideUpload = true;
   } else {
    this.hideUpload = false;
   }
   if("viewMode"){
    this.w9ReadOnly = true;
   } else {
    this.w9ReadOnly = false;
   }
   const control = <FormArray>this.agentW9InfoForm.get('w9Info');
   let info = [];
   info.push(w9)
   for (const emp of info) {
     console.log(emp,"emp")
    const grp = this.FB.group({
      taxIdNumber: [emp.taxId, Validators.required],
      signatureDate: [emp.signatureDate, [Validators.required]],
      businessType: [emp.businessType, [Validators.required]],
      uploadFile:[emp.uploadFile]
    });
    console.log(grp.controls.value,"grp");
    control.push(grp);
  }

  }
```

DEMO:
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser-table%2Fuser-table.component.ts)

Comment: control.controls = []; this line before let info=[]; that will make your formArray to empty

Comment: @MustafaKunwa thanks for the response, it helped but on click of save, i need to send all data along with the updated changes if any, how can that be done?

Comment: You are saving FormArray? You can keep flag of which all object you edited

Comment: ya i am speaking about formArray, but here for example, i have 3 records among that 2 records i have edited and created 1 more record, so totally 4 records must go during save/edit, with the updated changes if any

Comment: 1 is not edited so 3?

Comment: ok il check for this again with them, based on row edit/view button click, how can i make controls enable/disable?